# why dosent new values from mysql databse show up in my table in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table, mysql-workbench

i made a table in php with values from a mysql table. However, only the values that i put directly in the mysql schema in mysql workbench show up. When i try to add new values through the website, they appear in the schema in mysql workbench, but not in my table on my site! I have tried to put new values directly  in the schema, but they will not show up either. below is my code. I am very greatful for all help, but as i am a beginner i would really apricate straight foward explanations. Thanks in advance! below is also a screenshot of my database

```
$sql= "select fname, lname, street, street_number, name,  tool, startyear, adress.adress_id, person.person_id ,person.adress_id
from person
join personsport
on person.person_id= personsport.person_id
join sport
on personsport.sport_id = sport.sport_id
join adress
on person.adress_id= adress.adress_id ORDER BY lname";

$resultat= $kobling->query($sql);
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th> Fornavn  </th>";
echo "<th> Etternavn </th>";
echo "<th> Adresse </th>";
echo "<th> Sport </th>";
echo "<th> Utstyr</th>";
echo "<th> Start år</th>";

while ($rad=$resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
$fornavn=$rad["fname"];
$etternavn=$rad["lname"];
$gate=$rad["street"];
$gatenumber=$rad["street_number"];
$sport=$rad["name"];
$utstyr=$rad["tool"];
$startår=$rad["startyear"];
$adress_id=$rad["adress_id"];
$person_id=$rad["person_id"];

$adresse= $gate." ".$gatenumber;
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$fornavn</td>";
echo "<td>$etternavn</td>";
echo "<td><a href='oversiktligfamilie.php?adress_id=$adress_id'> $adresse </a></td>";
echo "<td>$sport</td>";
echo "<td>$utstyr</td>";
echo "<td>$startår</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

```
select fname, lname, street, street_number, name,  tool, startyear, adress.adress_id, person.person_id ,person.adress_id
from person
join personsport
on person.person_id= personsport.person_id
join sport
on personsport.sport_id = sport.sport_id
join adress
on person.adress_id= adress.adress_id ORDER BY lname
```

[image: database]

Comment: Make sure you do `commit` after you insert values into the table. Having said that, it is difficult to analyze the problem using the code snippet you have shared.

Comment: i see! i was trying to minimize code, but i am a beginner:) what more information should i include?

Comment: *"Make sure you do commit after you insert values into the table"* @MathewsMathai might help but most likley not as there is a thing called [auto_commit mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html) in MySQL

Comment: .. -> *"In InnoDB, all user activity occurs inside a transaction. If autocommit mode is enabled, each SQL statement forms a single transaction on its own. By default, MySQL starts the session for each new connection with autocommit enabled, so MySQL does a commit after each SQL statement if that statement did not return an error. If a statement returns an error, the commit or rollback behavior depends on the error."*

Comment: *" what more information should i include? "*   MySQL table structure(s) .. -> `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`  for every table involved in the query this also means including foreign key related tables... We need to see the insert PHP code aswell..   Plus we need to know if you got errors and if you are running PHP in debugging mode...

Comment: If the data is visible querying mysql directly with the same query then this sounds like browser caching - i.e. a misunderstanding.

Comment: Are you sure `$kobling` is successfully connected to MySQL? try using `var_dump and die();`  for the resulting variable of each step. Hopefully, it helps.

Comment: @Ali, yes it is connected, but thanks:)

Comment: when i tried to use the SELECT code previous described, i only got the same results that showed on my site. can it be because it only shows rows when all the columns have values?

Comment: Was this resolved? I just happened to come by this post again.